# How to skip files while refreshing full copy sandbox?

Tags: metadata, sobject, files, refresh, full-sandbox

Not having a chance to exercise on production I need to recommend our administrator steps to initiate full copy sandbox refresh process. We would like to not to copy files from production.
Is there a way to select specific sObject to not to be copied to skip Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want to look at sandbox templates:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5

Just be aware that you cannot select the records, it will be all for that object. Also some objects have dependencies so will require other objects, and their respective records.

For Files I believe it is Content Body you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks Gribot, I am aware of Sandbox Templates, which sObject should be removed to be sure that files won't be copied?

Comment: Updated answer, should be Content Body.